# Place border around multiple cells in a gridview

Tags: asp.net, css, gridview

So I have a Gridview that I would like to modify the look of for only certain cells, and I would like to treat those cells as one (if possible).

So first I am changing some of the cells background color on RowDataBound:

```
if (e.Row.RowIndex > 1 && e.Row.RowIndex < 7)
{
    e.Row.Cells[1].BackColor = Color.Red;
    e.Row.Cells[2].BackColor = Color.Red;
    e.Row.Cells[3].BackColor = Color.Red;
    e.Row.Cells[4].BackColor = Color.Red;
    e.Row.Cells[5].BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

This will change a 5x5 area of cells to red.  Now what I would like to do next is put a border around the outside of that 5x5 area.  I found the borderStyle and BorderColor for a cell, but is there a way for me to only turn on a border for one side of a cell so I can create my border?

Thanks

Comment: As walther said, use CSS - this type of thing is what CSS is for. Inline styles are evil! :)  Also, I'd add the border around the entire row. If you think about it, the row _should_ be related info, right? So if you highlight the entire row, the user _should_ understand something has changed in the row. Then, you could use the background color to show which cells changed specifically.

Comment: My data isn't row specific.  I am creating a weekly time schedule with some "core hours" that need to be covered, which cross rows.

Comment: ok, I see. I am not sure that you'll be able to achieve the effect you are looking for, but you can certainly use `background-color`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd advise you to use classes instead, don't hard-code it like this. It will be easier to maintain etc.

Comment: So i just need to make a class for each corner and the sides of the border and assign as needed, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I just thought I would post this as a solution, in case anyone else is looking to do this.

Here is my CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
.LeftUpperCorner
{
    border-left:5px solid black;
border-top:5px solid black;
}

.Top
 {
border-top:5px solid black;
 }

 .RightUpperCorner
 {
border-right:5px solid black;
border-top:5px solid black;
}

.Left
{
border-left:5px solid black;
}

.Right
{
border-right:5px solid black;
}

.LeftLowerCorner
{
border-left:5px solid black;
border-bottom:5px solid black;
}

.Bottom
{
border-bottom:5px solid black;
}

.RightLowerCorner
{
border-right:5px solid black;
border-bottom:5px solid black;
}
```

and my code behind:

```
            if (e.Row.RowIndex == 2)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[1].CssClass = "LeftUpperCorner";
            e.Row.Cells[2].CssClass = "Top";
            e.Row.Cells[3].CssClass = "Top";
            e.Row.Cells[4].CssClass = "Top";
            e.Row.Cells[5].CssClass = "RightUpperCorner";
        }

        if (e.Row.RowIndex == 3 || e.Row.RowIndex == 4 || e.Row.RowIndex == 5)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[1].CssClass = "Left";
            e.Row.Cells[5].CssClass = "Right";
        }

        if (e.Row.RowIndex == 6)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[1].CssClass = "LeftLowerCorner";
            e.Row.Cells[2].CssClass = "Bottom";
            e.Row.Cells[3].CssClass = "Bottom";
            e.Row.Cells[4].CssClass = "Bottom";
            e.Row.Cells[5].CssClass = "RightLowerCorner";
        }
```

It may not be the prettiest, but this has not real need to change, and will always be in the same location, so it fits my simple needs.